# Delphi TRibbon control: how to use the context sensitive help?

Tags: delphi, ribbon

we're using Delphi 2009's TRibbon control with the ScreenTipsManager.  in the footer of the tip it says "Press F1 for more help".  how can we show help for the tip currently shown?  eg:  your mouse is over a button and a tip is shown for the button...how can we determine which hint is being shown so we can find the help to show when they press F1?

Answer (score 2):

Each screen tip is assigned to an action defined in the action manager which is attached to your ribbon control. Each action (TAction) has three properties regarding to context-sensitive help:

- HelpContext
- HelpKeyworkd
- HelpType

Depending on the way you are using your context-sensitive help, you can give them value. This way, if you define a help file for your project, every time your user presses F1, your app will try to open the help file, and go to the topic inside the help file which corresponds to the value of HelpContext or HelpKeyword of the active control.

Comment: It also require to setup the correct help system (add the proper uses), and of course if the help file(s) has been correctly created.